# drf-mongoengine DynamicDocumentSerializer doesn't include embedded field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I'm using

> django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.3.0
>
> mongoengine==0.10.5

```
class MyModel2(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
     sn = mongoengine.StringField()
     # more fields

class MyModel(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    field1 = mongoengine.StringField(unique=True)
    field2 = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    field3 = mongoengine.BooleanField()
    field4 = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(MyModel2)
```

and here is the serializer

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DynamicDocumentSerializer

class MyModelSerializer(DynamicDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field4')
```

but in my api returns only `field1, field2, field3`. even after explicitly mentioning the `field4`

```
class myListAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
     model = MyModel
     serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
     queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to create a separate serializer for that and include in your main serializer

create Model2 serializer

```
class MyModel2Serializer(DynamicDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel2
        fields = ('sn',)
```

and include in your serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(DynamicDocumentSerializer):
    field4 = MyModel2Serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field4')
```